Как на VUE реализовать многодокументное приложение на основе диалоговых (модальных) окон?
Сейчас у меня есть классическое SPA приложение реализованное с использованием стека VUE, VUE Router, VUEX, Vuetify.
Недавно увидел реализацию интерфейса основанное на редактировании данных в диалоговых (модальных) окнах (например Битрикс, Сбер Бизнес).
В результате изучения данных приложений я понял, что эти модальные окна открываются в зависимости от значения URL адреса, причем они накладываются друг на друга (т.е. в один момент времени может быть открыто множество окон - своего рода MDI приложение для Windows). Насколько я понимаю нужно как то хранить список открытых модальных окон в Vuex.Подскажите, куда копать, чтобы реализовать такой же интерфейс на VUE или может быть уже есть готовое решение?
Спасибо!

На главной странице app.vue замапь историю на страницу в окна. Там v-for и в таг RouterView с параметром path равным элементу истории. Переход по ссылкам будет создавать окна. Ключ выставить на роут чтоб окна не дублировались или через массив почистить можно.

Интересная задумка, правда в плане ux мне кажется не очень)
